# <identifier> expected in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to load the data from the properties file in my class.But i am getting error `<identifier> expected`.I am not getting what i have done wrong in this please suggest me what i have done wrong.

```
public class ToDoList {

  private Properties prop = new Properties();
  {
        prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties"));//Here i am getting the error
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Error is like

```
<identifier> expected
illegal start of type
')' expected
';' expected
illegal start of type
<identifier> expected
';' expected
invalid method declaration; return type required
';' expected
```

Comment: What Version of Java? And are you intentionally trying to use anonymous inner classes?

Comment: @Seth  i  have methods in the class but i haven't posted that

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment, are you trying to use anonymous inner classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `try` keyword.  It should be

```
try {
// statements
} catch (IOException ioe) {
// handle exception
}
```

And don't forget to put your code inside a method.

Comment: Java is not a procedural language, so if you need to execute something like the `load` statement you have, it needs to be placed inside a callable block like constructor, method, or class initialization block.

Answer (score 0):

You used an initializer block `{ ... }` but that cannot have a catch block, neither a try.

At that level only field, constructor, class and method declarations are allowed.

My solutions, place all in a constructor.

```
public ToDoList() {
    try {
        prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties"));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume that your properties-file looks like:

```
someName1=someValue1
someName2=someValue2
someName3=someValue3
```

In my case the properties-file is in the root folder of the project.

But this is not necessary.

```
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try
        {
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./test.properties");
            prop.load(input);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(prop.get("someName1"));
        System.out.println(prop.get("someName2"));
        System.out.println(prop.get("someName3"));
    }
}
```

this shows me the values i set in the properties file

Mind that you are not calling any function in your code:

```
public class ToDoList {
//Here you declare your properties
  private Properties prop = new Properties();
  {// this is not a function
        prop.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties"));//Here i am getting the error
  }
  catch (IOException ioe) // you dont start a try-clause
  {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Change it to:

```
public class ToDoList {

  private Properties prop = new Properties();
public ToDoList(){ //Constructor of the class
  try{
// declare the inputstream with that file
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("file.properties");
     prop.load(input);
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
// Error handling code here
    ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```